# Unable to find rest resource using spring boot with angular

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have my simple project setup like this:

angular-controller:

```
myApp.controller('signupCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, auth) {
    "ngInject";

    function successAuth(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }

    $scope.addUser = function () {
        $scope.userData = {
            email: $scope.user.email,
            password: $scope.user.password
        };
        console.log("form: ", $scope.userData);
        angular.element('#register-modal').modal('hide');

        auth.signup($scope.userData, successAuth, function (error) {
            $rootScope.error = error;
            console.log($rootScope.error);
        });
    };
});
```

angular-service:

```
myApp.service('auth', function($http){

    return {
        signup: function(data,success, error){
            $http.post('/registration/', data).success(success).error(error);
        },
        login: function(data,success, error){
            $http.post('login', data).success(success).error(error);
        }
    };
});
```

Spring-controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void registration(User userBean) {
        System.out.println("register");
        System.out.println("name: " + userBean.getUsername());
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I do form submit from angular web page, Its not hitting the spring controller at all. I get not found(404) in console. Why is it so?

Comment: Are AngularJS files packed with Java application?

Comment: @BranislavLazic I didn't get you?

Comment: Are AngularJS JavaScript files inside of Java project or they are separated from Java application running on some other server?

Comment: @BranislavLazic Yeah they are in same project

Comment: @BranislavLazic Strange I had to use dispatcher-servlet.xml for it to work. I heard that spring boot takes care of it automatically.